# Two way database synchronization using Kafka

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka

We would like to build a system that has one main Postgres database in the headquarter and many local databases in various regional offices.

The main database will have a copy of the data from all regional offices databases.

No table will be modified by both the headquarter and the local office.   Each table will either be modified only by the HQ and the changes will be synchronized to the regional offices, or it will only be modified by the local office and synced to the HQ database.

Please note that each local database will have a different subset of data from the HQ database.  No two local databases will have the same data.

What is the best way of implementing this.  Kafka? SQL scripts? Or some other option.

Your input is most welcome.

Comment: You can use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html)

Comment: Sounds like overkill for Kafka, unless you also need the data elsewhere. Direct db-db replication is almost always best done with db-specific tools

Comment: It’s depend what infrastructure in your organization...Are there are any specific ETL tool you are using or big data or stream like kafka Spark etc...or believe in custom build...question is open ended

Answer (score 0):

From your use-case it looks like you want to set a Multi Master replication system. We are currently providing two complete solutions to your problem one is EDB Postgres Replication Server 6.2 (Data replication for Postgres),

You may see the details here:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/enterprise-postgres/edb-postgres-replication-server

and can download from here:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/edb-postgres-replication-server

The second solution to your problem is the soon to be released EDB Replicate which is using the Apache Kafka message streaming for replicating changes between databases and Apache Zookeeper configuration management.

If you are interested in details on EDB Replicate drop us a note at info@enterprisedb.com.

Disclaimer: I worked for EnterpriseDB.